# Finding concavity using a second derivative that is never greater than zero.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

When is $\frac{3x-8}{4(2-x)^{3/2}} > 0$?

The equation above is the second derivative of the function:
$$f(x) = x\sqrt{2-x}$$

I am wanting to find the concavity of the original function. I know that $f(x)$ is concave up when $f''(x)>0$

Since there are no solutions to $\frac{3x-8}{4(2-x)^{3/2}} > 0$, does this mean that $f(x) = x\sqrt{2-x}$ is never concave up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, $f(x) = x\sqrt{2-x}$ is never concave up because the second derivative, $f''(x)$, is never positive.